# Is it possible to assign and return a variable simultaneously?

Tags: c++, function, oop

Let's say I write a function as such:

```
bool Ship::processHit()
{
    health--;
    return !health = sunk;
}
```

Will this set `sunk` to the same value as `!health`?

Comment: You want to return the value of !health and sunk together ?

Comment: what do you mean by !health after decrementing it .It is an integer, how are you negating it ?

Comment: Assignment is always right to left. If you want `sunk` to get the same value as `!health` (and return that value) then you need to reverse the assignment.

Comment: Is this compiled successfully?

Comment: `!health = sunk;` is equivalent to `(!health) = sunk;`  I can't believe that would actually compile.

Comment: @selbie Really? Which compiler compiled that code?

Comment: @ArdentCoder - you didn't read my comment: *I **can't believe** that would actually compile*.  Translation: I know that code can't possibly compile unless my understanding of operator precedence is just wrong.

Comment: @selbie Lol, English is my third language

Comment: As an aside, it's not a particularly good practice to hide things that change a variable's value within a larger statement. Most people would appreciate having it broken up into assignment on one line and returning on the next because it's much more obvious that `sunk` is being changed. It's easy to scan the `return` line, see the `return` keyword, and stop reading.

Comment: I think you thoroughly confused yourself already in an earlier step.To clarify that confusion please answer to yourself the following: `int a=5; int b=6; a=b; return b;` What value will be returned here? Maybe try by building and running it, then explain it to yourself. Then compare to your shown code.

Comment: @selbie: As types are not shown, with custom types, we might make the code compile, and even have OP expected behavior. [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ade5f04038bb16bc)

Comment: @Demo - sure. theoretically.

Comment: @selbie: Demo is the code link, not my pseudo :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool Ship::processHit()
{
    health--;
    return !health = sunk;
}
```

You can't do this (assuming that `health` is not an instance of a user defined datatype with the necessary operator overloads).

> Will this set sunk to the same value as !health?

No, you are actually doing the opposite and inviting more errors. `!health` is not an lvalue, so what are you assigning `sunk` to!?

> Is it possible to assign a variable and return simultaneously?

**Yes**.

Replace `return !health = sunk;`

With `return sunk = !health;`

Comment: What you say is fine.   May also wish to encourage not doing an assignment in a return statement, and break `return sunk = !health` into two statements, `sunk = !health; return sunk;`.   While giving the same net effect, having an assignment within a larger statement makes code harder to read, easier to get wrong, and easier to break when someone does maintenance of the code.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I agree. That was just a short yes/no type answer :P Your comment has added more value to it :)